# How to call javascript function without changing its previous value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, switch-statement

I need to call a javascript function any number of times without changing the previous vales of it.
I have a json called icon which has 15 icons in it
and i am using switch statement to call the function of respective icon.
I have problem when map icon comes, because map icon usually groups all icons which means it can have even another map icon in it. Below is my code.

```
for(var i = 0;i<icon.length;i++) {
   switch(icon.type) {
      case 1:
         display();
      case 2:
         map();
      ..
   }
}
```

And the map function will be like

```
function map() {
   for(var i = 0;i<icon.length;i++) {
      switch(icon.type) {
         case 1:
            display();
         case 2:
            map();
         ..
      }
   }
}
```

If a map function calls its own function again, the values in the main map function overrides. I dont know how to make a call to its own function without changing the previous values.. 
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: "*the values in the main map function overrides*" - which ones? Please be more specific and show the whole code. It seems likely that you have unintentionally global variables or so, usually such recursion would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood correct Your problem, but You can try to use technique called memoization. It is used to cache result of a previously calculated value thus can avoid the need to recalculate.

And here is simple example how this could be done

```
function isPrime(value) {
if (!isPrime.anwers) isPrime.answers = {};
if (isPrime.answers[value] != null) {
    return isPrime.answers[value];
}

var prime = value != 1; // 1 can never be prime

for (var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
    if (value % i == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
     }
}

return isPrime.answers[value] = prime;
}
```